# What is the best way to add cell neighbors

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a grid, grid is and 2-demension array of Cell object.

```
public class Cell
{
  int x;
  int y;
  ArrayList<Cell> nighbors=new ArrayList<Cell>();

  public void addNeighbor(Cell cell)
  {
    this.neighbors.add(cell);
  }
}
```

Every cell have 8 neighbors:

[image]

And also, one more, field is looped, like on the picture below:

[image]

So the neighbors for Cell(0,1) are also cells (5,0), (5,1), (5,2).

Now I fill neigbors like that:

```
public void addNeigbors(int x, int y)
{
  Cell curentCell=grid[x][y];
  if(x==0)
  {
    if(y==0)
    {
            curentCell.addNiegbor(this.cells[this.width-1][this.height-1]);
            curentCell.addNiegbor(this.cells[x][this.height-1]);
            curentCell.addNiegbor(this.cells[x+1][this.height-1]);
            curentCell.addNiegbor(this.cells[x+1][y]);
            curentCell.addNiegbor(this.cells[x+1][y+1]);
            curentCell.addNiegbor(this.cells[x][y+1]);
            curentCell.addNiegbor(this.cells[this.width-1][y+1]);
            curentCell.addNiegbor(this.cells[this.width-1][y]);
    }
    else if(y==this.height-1)
    {
       // similar code
    }
    else
    {
      // and so on
    }
  }
  // and so on 
}
```

This code make my cry but I have no idea to make it better.

What can you advise me?

Comment: Hint: just in case you are working on Conways "game of life" ... there are many many other ways to represent cells; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life for example.

Comment: @Jägermeister You are right. I've reviewed the architecture and have no need to store cell neighbors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this :

```
public void addNeigbors(int x, int y)
{
  Cell curentCell=grid[x][y];
  int xp1 = (x+1)%width;
  int xm1 = (x-1+width)%width;
  int yp1 = (y+1)%height;
  int ym1 = (y-1+height)%height;
  curentCell.addNiegbor(this.cells[xp1][y]);
  curentCell.addNiegbor(this.cells[xp1][yp1]);
  curentCell.addNiegbor(this.cells[xp1][ym1]);
  curentCell.addNiegbor(this.cells[x][yp1]);
  curentCell.addNiegbor(this.cells[x][ym1]);
  curentCell.addNiegbor(this.cells[xm1][y]);
  curentCell.addNiegbor(this.cells[xm1][yp1]);
  curentCell.addNiegbor(this.cells[xm1][ym1]);
}
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Storing references to each neighbor in Cell is a waste.  IF cells need to access their neighbors, then put a reference to the `grid` array in each cell, and let cell calculate its neighbor indexes on the fly when necessary.

You could add a method like this:

```
Cell getNeighbor(int dx, int dy)
{
    int w = grid.length;
    int h = grid[x].length;
    return grid[(x+w+dx)%w][(y+h+dy)%h];
}
```

If a cell needs to iterate through all of its neighbors, you can do it like this:

```
for (int dy=-1;dy<=1;++dy) {
   for(int dx=-1;dx<=1;++dx) {
       if (dx!=0 || dy!=0) {
           processNeighbor(getNeighbor(dx,dy));
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: You might not want to have the cell know the grid.

Answer (score 1):

Create an (static) array that conains the x/y delta for all 8 neighbors so you can loop through it an add the delta to your cells x/y coordinates to get the neighbor coordinates and use `mod -> %` to deal with the borders:

```
public class Cell {
  int x;
  int y;
  private static int delta[][] = {{-1,0},{-1,-1},{0,-1},{1,-1},{1,0},{1,1},{0,1},{-1,1}};

  ArrayList < Cell > neighbors = new ArrayList < Cell > ();

  public void addNeighbors() {
    for (int i = 0; i < delta.length; i++) {
      this.neighbors.add(this.cells
        [Math.floorMod(this.x + delta[i][0], width)]
        [Math.floorMod(this.y + delta[i][1], height)]
      );
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over possible variations on x (`dx`) and y (`dy`), avoid the special case `dx = dy = 0` and use `mod` to wrap around the grid.

```
public void addNeigbors(int x, int y) {
  for(int dx = -1; dx <= 1; dx++) {
    for(int dy = -1; dy <= 1; dy++) {
      if(dx != 0 || dy != 0) {
        int nx = Math.floorMod(x + dx, this.width);
        int ny = Math.floorMod(y + dy, this.height);
        this.cells[x][y].addNeighbors(this.cells[nx][ny]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you use for loops why not just loop from x-1 to x+1 instead of executing add twice?

Comment: @FabianN. You are absolutely right, but I find the current form to show more clearly what is going on.